# how to solve cors Allow Access control in vue js and laravel application

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, cors, middleware

I Have tried almost everything. My front end is developed in vue js . backend is in laravel. we have written api for another website from which we are trying to fetch data. If directly access that website Url it gives all the data but when i try to access it from my website with axios it gives me this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/tickets/fetch_tickets?page=undefined' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-requested-with is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

that website form which i am trying to fetch data also build in laravel. i have created middleware and applied it on api routes. I added chrome extension `Allow Cors` with which it works fine but we cant ask every client to use that extension.

We access that url from other website which is accessing data nicely. only vue js app creating these issue.

**Vue Code**

```
    getTickets() {

      axios.get( 'example.com/api/tickets/fetch_tickets?page=' + this.pagination.current, {


      }).then((response) => {
        // console.log(res.data.data)
        // this.desserts = res.data.data;
        // this.loadingprop = false;
        this.desserts = response.data.data;
        this.pagination.current = response.data.current_page;
        this.pagination.total = response.data.last_page;
        console.log(response.data.data);
      }).catch((err) => {
        this.handleErrors(err.response.data.errors);
      })
        .then(() => {
          this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

**other website's routes**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api','cors']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'tickets'], function () {

        Route::post('/store_ticket_auth', 'TicketApiController@storeTicketAuth'); //enter ticket auth
        Route::get('/fetch_tickets', 'TicketApiController@fetchTickets'); //get all tickets
        Route::get('/fetch_replies/{ticket_id}', 'TicketApiController@fetchTicketReplies'); // get all replies by ticket id
        Route::post('/send_reply', 'TicketApiController@sendTicketReply'); // Send reply
        Route::post('/update_ticket', 'TicketApiController@updateTicketStatus'); // Update Status

    });
});
```

Do I need to add this on my cuurent project too?

```
return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

I think the issue is on client side but dont know why it is not working.

I tried all answers on stackoverflow but nothing works

Comment: - add following two lines in the top of public/index.php:  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");

Comment: I am using laravel

Comment: - there is asteric after colon as it is not showing in the above comment

Comment: - yes, in laravel go to public folder and edit index.php file and add above two lines in the top. thats all

Comment: Ok. and on which project i would add it? on my project from where i am accessing it. or on other project from where data is coming? source project or desination project?

Comment: - from where the data is coming, in your case the data is coming from Laravel.

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220271/discussion-between-muhammad-sadiq-and-web-pakistan).

Comment: If you are using Vuejs cli, following link can be useful: [Medium](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3).

Comment: I noticed that if there's an error from backend being returned as plain text then a CORS error will show since accepted/json is expected

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to add these lines in my **index.php** file of laravel

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "OPTIONS") {//send back preflight request response
return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved my issues by commenting out:

```
// window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

in resources/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: whoa, that's the ticket, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the server won't allow the client to use a `x-requested-with` header.

In php you can do this to allow the server to accept that header:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
```

Comment: I am using laravel framework already added this in middleware but not working

Answer (score -1):

If you want the easy way you can use [laravel-cors](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors)

You can follow the installation step and add this code in your config/cors.php

```
'allow_origins' => [
    'https://yourfrontendrequest.url',
],
```

Comment: on which project i need to add this , from which i am fetching data or on my project?

Comment: The one that use laravel, the receiver

Comment: source project or desination project?

Comment: the source project

Comment: Not working it seems like issue is on client side.. if you direct access that url in your browser bar it shows data

Comment: but now error is change ```'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.```

Comment: if you're using the *, then 1 is enough, it's mean all URL can access it

Comment: maybe you can try some of the way to solve it from here https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/63

Comment: Now it is working a bit. when i make request first time it works but in next attempt it gives same error

Comment: you know its pagination. first page appear when request for next page it gives error

Answer (score -1):

Install  [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc/related?hl=en) Chrome extension and

Then go to resources/js/bootstrap.js and comment out this line  `// window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`

Answer (score -3):

you can disable same origin policy in chrome

1. press win + R
2. and then copy this :

   chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Comment: i dont want it to work only on my computer, it should work on server too

Comment: This is not a real solution since this will only work for the person doing this. Which is a bad hackfix, by the way.