# Vue js Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, cors

I have a laravel application with Vue running on the front end. The application is running on the localhost:8000, on the Vue side, I am trying to fetch data from another API e.g https://someapi.com/. However, I am getting this error, `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://someapi.com/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Research about the error brought me to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537112/how-to-solve-cors-allow-access-control-in-vue-js-and-laravel-application), [this](https://thewebtier.com/laravel/handle-cors-requests-vuejs-client-laravel-api/), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218774/cors-laravel-vuejs) as well as others but none works for me.

I created middleware:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        $headers = [
         'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return response()->make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }
        
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

then added it to routemiddleware array in Kernel.php:

```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
       
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
    ];
```

then protected welcome route with it:

```
Route::middleware(['auth','cors'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

Comment: "Could someone point where I am doing it wrongly?" — No, because we can't see your attempt so we can't tell where you went wrong. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Alright, thank you for pointing that out. I have edited the question

Comment: Are you able to use the inspector to see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers? I've had issues in the past where two have been set and it ignores both.

Comment: Did you try with this package? https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: @AlexisGatuingt Yes, I tried with it but it didn't work